# Azure Management Certificates: error 403

Tags: azure, certificate

I have an Azure subscription and I have several clients that use the management API. I also have several certificates uploaded in the Azure portal. When the certificates were created (self signed using Windows IIS) they worked properly, but after a while they just stop working. 
Yesterday, I created a management certificate and uploaded it and it was working just fine. Today, when I make an API call with that same certificate, I get error 403 (forbidden). This happened with several certificates, but not all of them. I created the first certificate few months ago and this one is workig fine, but the other ones I created since then have been causing these problems. All certificates are valid, and they have not been deleted from the portal.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Any sugestions or ideas what might be the cause of the problem?